# Couldn't charge gocardless customer immediately in sandbox

Tags: c#, .net, gocardless

The problem is that i couldn't charge gocardless customer immediately in sandbox account. Once i've created payment through .net sdk, it automatically set charge day in 6 days after now. Below how i create new gocardless payment for customer:

```
var createResponse = await _goCardlessClient.Payments.CreateAsync(new PaymentCreateRequest()
        {
            Amount = 10,
            Currency = PaymentCreateRequest.PaymentCurrency.GBP,
            Links = new PaymentCreateRequest.PaymentLinks()
            {
                Mandate = "mandateId goes here",
            },
            Metadata = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { metadata goes here }
            },
            IdempotencyKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
        });
```

When i'm trying to explicitly set charge date in the following way:

```
            var createResponse = await _goCardlessClient.Payments.CreateAsync(new PaymentCreateRequest()
        {
            Amount = 10,
            Currency = PaymentCreateRequest.PaymentCurrency.GBP,
            ChargeDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
            Links = new PaymentCreateRequest.PaymentLinks()
            {
                Mandate = "mandateId goes here",
            },
            Metadata = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { metadata goes here }
            },
            IdempotencyKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
        });
```

i get an exceptions says that:

> charge_date must be on or after mandate's next_possible_customer_charge_date

And in official documentation i couldn't find any info about how to set next_possible_customer_charge_data explicitly for sandbox. Does anyone sort it out?

Comment: https://developer.gocardless.com/api-reference/#core-endpoints-mandates
Have you double check what is the Mandate earliest charge date?

Comment: You having this problem because you have a mandate that has a "earliest_charge_date", and the payment you currently have is too close to the charge date. GoCardless stops you from charging the customer as an attempt to avoid double charging or charging wrong amounts. You have two solutions, you set a payment in a future date of the mandate "next_possible_customer_charge_date" or you create a new mandate with past dates or even more in the future of your payment. I would allow a gap of about 5 days.

Comment: You need to create/collect the payment 3 working days advance notice. more details https://gocardless.com/guides/posts/advance-notice/